# Tesseract OCR Read Horizontally rather than Vertically C#

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

We have a C# .Net app that is using Tesseract to do Optical Character Recognition (OCR) on .tiff files.  Here's an Example:
[image: Example tiff fiel that Tesseract reads]

We are then outputting the data to a text file.  However, Tesseract is reading the data in a Vertical fashion.  In my example image, it is reading the tiff as two columns of data and the data the data is being outputted from Tesseract like this:

TYPE:
DATE:
Address:
City:
State:
Owner:
Owner Type:
Acreage:
Mortgage:
12345 
2017-04-06 
100 Main St. 
Some City 
Some State 
John Doe 
Primary 
10.25 
Yes

What we want is Tesseract to read the tiff file horizontally and have the output look like this:

TYPE:12345 
DATE:2017-04-06 
Address:100 Main St. 
City:Some City 
State:Some State 
Owner:John Doe 
Owner Type:Primary 
Acreage:10.25
Mortgage:Yes

We've tried the various Page Sementation options for Tesseract, but they all produce the same result.

Has anyone run into this same issue? Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.  Tesseract has a set of config files.  Inside several of these config files is the setting **tessedit_pageseg_mode**.  This setting was set to 1 in all the config files.  `1=Automatic page segmentation with OSD.`  `OSD=Orientation and script detection.`

Bottom line, these config file settings were overwriting our command line argument.  Once I removed the **tessedit_pageseg_mode** parameter from the config files, our command line argument of

**-psm 6** worked and produced the output data in the desired format.

`psm=Page Segmentation Mode.  6=Assume a single uniform block of text`

**-psm 4** also worked

`psm=Page Segmentation Mode.  4=Assume a single column of text of variable sizes`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I ran into the same problem today.

setting the segmentation mode with `engine.SetVariable("tessedit_pageseg_mode", 6);` did not work.

And for some reason I didnt find it in the config files.

**Solution:**

```
engine.DefaultPageSegMode = PageSegMode.SingleBlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

In c# the code would be:

```
using var input = new OcrInput(somePdfStream);
var config = new TesseractConfiguration() { PageSegmentationMode = TesseractPageSegmentationMode.SingleBlock };
var result = new IronTesseract(config).Read(input);
var text = result.Text;
```