# How to improve read tesseract accuracy?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I want to get the following expected result. Can you give me any suggestions to improve the result?

- Input image

[image: Input image]

- Expected result

```
流 動 資 産
固 定 資 産
```

- Actual result

```
産 産
資 資
動 定
```

- To reproduce the result

```
$ git clone https://github.com/zono/ocr.git
$ cd ocr
$ git checkout 0f2541eac302dd1fe2efbbd3b36e7ba40a99d232
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker exec -it ocr /bin/bash
# /usr/local/bin/tesseract /ocr/src/bssample7.png stdout -l jpn
産 産
資 資
動 定
```

- Versions

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea

# tesseract -v
tesseract 4.1.1-rc2-22-g08899
 leptonica-1.79.0
  libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use another page-segmentation-method to get the expected result.

Try to append **--psm 6** to your command to make it look like this:

```
$ tesseract /ocr/src/bssample7.png outputfilename -l jpn --psm 6
```

Here you can read about the different methods:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality#page-segmentation-method

Kind regards

Comment: Thanks. I will try to find the desired result with the options you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from [Tesseract OCR Read Horizontally rather than Vertically C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259694/tesseract-ocr-read-horizontally-rather-than-vertically-c-sharp)

```
# /usr/local/bin/tesseract /ocr/src/bssample7.png stdout -l jpn --psm 6
流 動 資 産
固 定 資 産
```